# Custom post type category archive URL redirects to home page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I have created a Custom Post Type `Projects`. Below is my code. Everything is working fine, but when I click on a Category of this Post Type it redirects me to the Homepage. I have tried all possible methods, but I am still unable to find the issue.

```
   add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
    function create_posttype() {
     $args = array(
            'labels'             => array('name'=>__('Projects'), 'singular_name'=>__('Projects') ),
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' =>'projects','with_front'=>true ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'project_category','post_tag'),
        );

        register_post_type( 'Projects', $args );

    }
```

Here is my code for registering the taxonomy,

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_project_taxonomies', 0 );


function create_project_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Project category', 'taxonomy general name', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Project catgeory', 'taxonomy singular name', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search category', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Writers', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Category', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit category', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update catrgory', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New category', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New category Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate writers with commas', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove category', 'textdomain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used writers', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No category found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Project Category', 'textdomain' ),

    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'project_category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'project_category', 'Projects', $args );
}
```

Please guys, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `'public' => false,` to `'public' => true,` when using `register_taxonomy()`. Also, don't use capital letters for the post type name in `register_post_type()`. Here's the full updated code (make sure to save  permalinks after updating your code):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_project_taxonomies', 0 );

add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
    function create_posttype() {
     $args = array(
                    'labels'             => array('name'=>__('Projects'), 'singular_name'=>__('Projects') ),
                    'public'             => true,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'show_ui'            => true,
                    'show_in_menu'       => true,
                    'query_var'          => true,
                    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' =>'projects','with_front'=>true ),
                    'capability_type'    => 'post',
                    'has_archive'        => true,
                    'hierarchical'       => false,
                    'menu_position'      => null,
                    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments'),
                    'taxonomies'          => array( 'project_category','post_tag'),
            );

            register_post_type( 'projects', $args );

    }


function create_project_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x( 'Project category', 'taxonomy general name', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'singular_name'              => _x( 'Project catgeory', 'taxonomy singular name', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'search_items'               => __( 'Search category', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Writers', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'all_items'                  => __( 'All Category', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'parent_item'                => null,
            'parent_item_colon'          => null,
            'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit category', 'textdomain' ),
            'update_item'                => __( 'Update catrgory', 'textdomain' ),
            'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New category', 'textdomain' ),
            'new_item_name'              => __( 'New category Name', 'textdomain' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate writers with commas', 'textdomain' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove category', 'textdomain' ),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used writers', 'textdomain' ),
            'not_found'                  => __( 'No category found.', 'textdomain' ),
            'menu_name'                  => __( 'Project Category', 'textdomain' ),

    );

    $args = array(
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'public'                => false,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'project_category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'project_category', 'projects', $args );
}
```

Using a singular name for post type and category names is also a good guideline, but not a requirement.

Comment: Thank you for help @Dave. But it didn't work. i have created Category.php, category-project_category.php, taxonomy.php, taxonomy-project_category.php. BUt nothing helped. still facing same problem.

Comment: Hrmm, just double-checked, it's working for me -- I created a project named `project 1` and assigned it to the `Project Cat 1` Project Category. The *Project Cat 1* archive URL is working; it is: `http://domain.com/project_category/project-cat-1/` Also the `taxonomy-project_category.php` template is loaded. How are you generating the Project Category URLs? Do they match the same pattern that I showed?

Comment: [http://localhost/site/project_category/post1/ ]    here is link, in my case

Comment: Did not understand what is the issue, but found alternative solution, using **Numeric** Permalink Structure , everyting is working only the problem is [http://localhost/nieuw/**archives**/project_category/rail-ns-4000]  **archives** in link. this worked for me. didn't able to find the issue.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept the answer, it worked thanks, I did not know what was the problem, I shut down the computer and turned on after few hours and it was working... Surprise for me, it may be the cache.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out, Manoj!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating the Permalinks under Settings? There is a section at the bottom of that page that points to Category Base. I don't think you have to enter anything into that field, but maybe just click "Save Changes" at the bottom of the page. Hope that does it.